# Maximum sampling rate for accelerometer in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, accelerometer, uiaccelerometer

Does anybody know that what is the maximum sampling rate of the iphone accelerometer.
I want to have have high update rate. i set it to updateInterval to 1.0/ 300.0
But it seems that i am not getting that much update rate.

So can any body tell me that what is the maximum update rate that we can get or how i can get the high update rate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you use DeviceMotionUpdateInterval(1.0/200.0); and poll with motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(), and get acceleration with motionManager.deviceMotion.gravity the rate is doubled to 200 hz (tested working on my iphone SE)

Answer (score 3):

The max accelerometer and gyroscope sampling rate on the iPhone 6 is **100Hz**.  You can empirically test this yourself.  Here is the code.

```
/******************************************************************************/
// First create and initialize two NSMutableArrays. One for accel data and one
// for gyro data. Then create and initialize CMMotionManager.  Finally,
// call this function

- (void) TestRawSensors
{
   speedTest = 0.0001; // Lets try 10,000Hz
   motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = speedTest;
   motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = speedTest;


    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue: [NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
    withHandler: ^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
    {
       [rawAccelSpeedTest addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: accelerometerData.timestamp]];
       [rawAccelSpeedTest addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: accelerometerData.acceleration.x]];

       if (error)
       {
          NSLog(@"%@", error);
       }

       if (rawAccelSpeedTest.count > 100)
       {
          [motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];

          for (uint16_t i = 0; i < rawAccelSpeedTest.count; i+=2)
          {
             NSLog(@"Time: %f   Accel: %f", [rawAccelSpeedTest[i] doubleValue],
                                            [rawAccelSpeedTest[i+1] doubleValue]);
          }
       }
    }];


   [motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue: [NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                              withHandler: ^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error)
    {
       [rawGryoSpeedTest addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: gyroData.timestamp]];
       [rawGryoSpeedTest addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: gyroData.rotationRate.x]];

       if (error)
       {
          NSLog(@"%@", error);
       }

       if (rawGryoSpeedTest.count > 100)
       {
          [motionManager stopGyroUpdates];

          for (uint16_t i = 0; i < rawGryoSpeedTest.count; i+=2)
          {
             NSLog(@"Time: %f   Rate: %f", [rawGryoSpeedTest[i] doubleValue],
                                           [rawGryoSpeedTest[i+1] doubleValue]);
          }

       }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate some more on this. I get the raw data but how should I interpret it? Also what about the standard deviation. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Despite the documentation saying `The maximum frequency at which you can request updates is hardware-dependent but is usually at least 100 Hz.` it looks to me like the **maximum sample rate is still 100Hz**.

My approach to figure out was taking the existing sample code for CoreMotion called MotionGraphs and adapting the `startUpdates` function to look like this:

```
func startUpdates() {
    guard let motionManager = motionManager, motionManager.isGyroAvailable else { return }

    sampleCount = 0
    let methodStart = Date()

    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = TimeInterval(1.0/100000.0) // Hardcoded to something verfy fast
    motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: .main) { gyroData, error in
        self.sampleCount += 1
        //...view update code removed
        if (self.sampleCount >= 100) {
            let methodFinish = Date()
            let executionTime = methodFinish.timeIntervalSince(methodStart)
            print("Duration of 100 Gyro samples: \(executionTime)")
            self.stopUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

I also set `motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = TimeInterval(1.0/100000.0)` for good measure (in case it is a global rate).

With that code in place for both Accelerometer and Gyroscope I confirm that an iPhone 8 on iOS 11.4 still maxes out right around 100Hz for both.

```
Duration of 100 Accelerometer samples: 0.993090987205505
Duration of 100 Accelerometer samples: 0.995925068855286
Duration of 100 Accelerometer samples: 0.993505954742432
Duration of 100 Accelerometer samples: 0.996459007263184
Duration of 100 Accelerometer samples: 0.996203064918518

Duration of 100 Gyro samples: 0.989820957183838
Duration of 100 Gyro samples: 0.985687971115112
Duration of 100 Gyro samples: 0.989449977874756
Duration of 100 Gyro samples: 0.988754034042358
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe duplicate. Look at

[update frequency set for deviceMotionUpdateInterval it's the actual frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777799/update-frequency-set-for-devicemotionupdateinterval-its-the-actual-frequency)

[Actual frequency of device motion updates lower than expected, but scales up with setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034411/actual-frequency-of-device-motion-updates-lower-than-expected-but-scales-up-with)

The same should be valid if using old UIAccerometerDelegate interface.