# NSThread, NSOperation or GCD for CoreMotion and accurate timing purposes?

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance, timing, core-motion

I'm looking to do some high precision core motion reading (>=100Hz if possible) and motion analysis on the iPhone 4+ which will run continuously for the duration of the main part of the app.  It's imperative that the motion response and the signals that the analysis code sends out are as free from lag as possible.

My original plan was to launch a dedicated NSThread based on the code in the metronome project as referenced here: [Accurate timing in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485072/accurate-timing-in-ios), along with a protocol for motion analysers to link in and use the thread.  I'm wondering whether GCD or NSOperation queues might be better?

My impression after copious reading is that they are designed to handle a quantity of discrete, one-off operations rather than a small number of operations performed over and over again on a regular interval and that using them every millisecond or so might inadvertently create a lot of thread creation/destruction overhead.  Does anyone have any experience here?

I'm also wondering about the performance implications of an endless while loop in a thread (such as in the code in the above link). Does anyone know more about how things work under the hood with threads?  I know that iPhone4 (and under) are single core processors and use some sort of intelligent multitasking (pre-emptive?) which switches threads based on various timing and I/O demands to create the effect of parallelism...

If you have a thread that has a simple "while" loop running endlessly but only doing any additional work every millisecond or so, does the processor's switching algorithm consider the endless loop a "high demand" on resources thus hogging them from other threads or will it be smart enough to allocate resources more heavily towards other threads in the "downtime" between additional code execution?

Thanks in advance for the help and expertise...

Answer (score 0):

IMO the bottleneck are rather the sensors. The actual update frequency is most often not equal to what you have specified. See [update frequency set for deviceMotionUpdateInterval it's the actual frequency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777799/update-frequency-set-for-devicemotionupdateinterval-its-the-actual-frequency/6787427#6787427) and [Actual frequency of device motion updates lower than expected, but scales up with setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034411/actual-frequency-of-device-motion-updates-lower-than-expected-but-scales-up-wit)

Some time ago I made a couple of measurements using Core Motion and the raw sensor data as well. I needed a high update rate too because I was doing a Simpson integration and thus wnated to minimise errors. It turned out that the real frequency is always lower and that there is limit at about 80 Hz. It was an iPhone 4 running iOS 4. But as long as you don't need this for scientific purposes in most cases 60-70 Hz should fit your needs anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  Those links had some useful info such as CoreMotion does additional calculations on a separate thread to get attitude coords.  Still I'd like to know more about the general threading aspect of the question if anyone knows...